# Use results of MYSQL query in table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a query:

```
SELECT  year (F_ULT_CIERRE_MENSUAL) - 1 'Año %'
FROM    mpaises
where   COD_PAIS = $COD_PAIS
```

I would like to use the results in the title of a column.

```
<th class='header'>Año %</th>
```

I need the results to go between Ano and %.  Example it would display Ano 2011 %.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function of mysql:

```
SELECT  concat('Año ', year(F_ULT_CIERRE_MENSUAL) - 1,' %') as header
FROM    mpaises
where   COD_PAIS = $COD_PAIS
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the string while outputting. E.g.:

```
foreach($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<th class="header">Año '.$row['year'].' %</th>';
}
```